# How do I load an array of refs from Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase

Let's say I have an array of keys in my Firebase data which represents a relationship to another section of data. Here's an example:

```
{
    "messages": {
        "m1": {
            "text": "123"
        },
        "m2": {
            "text": "123"
        },
        "m3": {
            "text": "123"
        }
    },
    "rooms": {
        "r1": {
            "messages": {
                "1": "m1",
                "2": "m2",
                "3": "m3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We have 3 messages each with an ID, and a room that has a Firebase array of message IDs that belong in that room. This is a pretty common pattern on Firebase.

So, in code, I get an array of message IDs, which I iterate over to create Firebase Refs from.

```
let messageIDs = snapshot.value["messages"] as! [String]
var refs: [Firebase] = []
for mID in messageIDs {
    refs.append(Firebase("https://firebase.com/messages/" + mID))
}
```

All good. This works as expected.

Now I want to display all of these messages in a list. Is there a way to load all of these items at once? I could loop through these Refs and perform an observe once on each one, but then I would need to manage the results as they come back. Or perhaps that is the only way of doing it? Has anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the message happen to all be in a sequence, you can perform a [range query](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries) to get all of them. From the docs:

```
let ref = Firebase(url:"https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs")
ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryStartingAtValue("b").queryEndingAtValue("b\u{f8ff}")
   .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    println(snapshot.key)
})
```

But most likely the messages won't (always) be sequential. In that case you will indeed have to loop through them and load them each in turn with [`observeSingleEventOfType`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-once). This is indeed a bit more work in code, since you need to merge the results into a single list/array.

Many developers worry about the performance of this operation, but this is not as bad as you may initially think. The requests will all be pipelined over the socket that Firebase keeps open, so it's pretty likely the sequence will be:

> send request 1
>
> send request 2
>
> send request 3
>
> ... wait for the server a bit
>
> get response 1
>
> get response 2
>
> get response 3

The sending of the requests and the receiving of the responses are going to be close to each other, in between you're waiting for the latency once and for the database to find the items.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of, but glad to hear I at least had the right idea. I'll make a subclass that fetches a group of refs and returns the snapshots when they're all done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There may be more to the question and existing structure but perhaps this structure would simplify things?

```
messages:
    message_id_0: 
        msg_num: 1
        text: "123"
        room: r1
    message_id_1:
        msg_num: 1
        text: "123"
        room: r3
    message_id_2:
        msg_num: 2
        text: "123"
        room: r1
```

and then to get all of the messages for room r1

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("room").queryEqualToValue("r1")
   .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    println(snapshot.value)
})
```

would return all the messages in a single snapshot for room r1 with the msg_num (for ordering) and the text of each message.

The structure breaks the link between the node name and the data it contains which will add more flexibility. Oh, and it eliminates the need for an array; it's probably a good idea to avoid arrays in Firebase where possible.

Comment: While it doesn't quite answer my question - this is definitely useful for other purposes. Thanks!